# About a word "smug"

Tags: meaning

I appreciate your fantastic supports as always.

When reading a text, I encountered this word:

> complacency

And its synonyms are lined up as

> self-satisfaction, **smug.**

Since I didn't know the word "smug", I looked it up the dictionary and found the following definitions:

[image]

It seems to me the definition 2 and definition 3 are contradictory. Or does definition 2, where it says "giving an impression", means "giving deceptive" impression (though the quote by W.W. Jacobs below does not seem so at all)?

For further additional info, according to Merriam-Webster Unabridged, "scrupulous" means.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: I would say the definition does not imply or require truth. Someone that looks smug may indeed be respectable, etc, and appear so, or just appear so and not actually be. I would also say the 3rd definition there is the most common use case.

Comment: They actually go together for me. Someone who is scrupulously correct may be so proud of that that they visibly show their superiority. In other words I don't see the contradiction between the two.

Comment: If you kindly think twice about the statement of the definition, I just would be perplexed. Sorry, since they would be the first souse.

Comment: The example for meaning 2 was written around 1900. I'm not sure the word is still used with that meaning.

Comment: I think then Merriam would "obsolete" mark then. They put the meaning of words around late 19th and early 20th as "obsolete".

Comment: I agree with James Random: I do not recognise that meaning for _smug_.

Comment: The OED gives a definition of  "Trim, neat, spruce, smart; in later use, having a self-satisfied, conceited, or consciously respectable air."   I've personally never encountered it except in the sense of self-satisfied and conceited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) gives three shorter but similar—and in this case quite helpful—definitions of *smug*:

> **smug** *adj.* **smugger; smuggest** {prob[ably] mod[ification] of L[ower] G[erman] *smuck* neat, fr[om] M[idle] L[ow] G[erman] *smucken* to dress; akin to O[ld] E[nglish] *smoc* smock}  (1551) **1 :** trim or smart in dress : SPRUCE **2 :** scrupulously clean, neat, or correct : TIDY **3 :** highly self-satisfied

So we have a word that emerged in English around 1550 with a sense akin to "dapper" but later acquired a second meaning that emphasized scrupulous (that is, very careful) neatness. After that, again at an unspecified date, came a somewhat bigger jump to a third meaning, "self-satisfied."

Today, the vast majority of instances of *smug* in English use the word in this third sense—it is not a term of admiration. You are certainly correct that dictionaries normally indicate outdated meanings with labels such as "rare" or "obsolete"—but Merriam-Webster is far less inclined to assign such labels these days than it was before 1961 (when it published the *Third New International Dictionary*). It may be worth noting that if the usage remains current in some part of the English-speaking world, a dictionary may take the view that it is still Standard English in that sense.

On the other hand, if you had consulted *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, fifth edition (2011), you would have found a single definition listed in its entry for *smug*:

> **smug** *adj.* **smugger, smuggest** Exhibiting or feeling great or offensive satisfaction with oneself or with one's situation; self-righteously complacent: *a smug look; a smug critic*. {Perhaps akin to Low German *smuck*, neat < Middle Low German < *smucken*, to adorn}

Clearly, *AHDEL* takes the position that only one meaning of *smug* is in current use in English: the meaning corresponding to definition 3 in Merriam-Webster. These are the kinds of things on which lexicographers can disagree, but in my opinion *AHDEL* is a more accurate source than Merriam-Webster for the meaning of *smug* as used today.

For historical perspective, I checked *Webster's Collegiate Dictionary*, fourth edition (1931). It shows the word *smug* at an interesting transitional phase in its contemporaneous meaning:

> **smug,** *a.* SMUGGER; -GEST Primly or affectedly neat, nice, or proper, as in dress; characterized by, or of or pert[aining] to a commonplace, self-satisfied, and affectedly or primly proper air or character.

It seems to me that the crucial element in the transition from Merriam-Webster's definition 2 to MW's definition 3 is the air of primness or hyper-correctness undergirding the self-satisfaction. In more-recent decades, I believe, *smug* has lost much of that element of punctilious or overexact propriety; instead, the word as used today emphasizes a self-satisfaction that verges on gloating.

Comment: Thank you. The usage of word changes so that in today's English world, if the words is used by the meaning 3 ( mostly ), then I have to accept it. Thank you.

Comment: If the word currently has mostly negative connotations, what is the meaning of [SmugMug](http://SmugMug.com) (a photo sharing service)? Is there a hidden irony or something?

Comment: @Zeus: I can't explain it—but then again I can't explain why a microbrewery would name itself  "[Arrogant Bastard Brewing Company](https://www.arrogantbrewing.com/)." My first thought is, "Maybe they don't understand what the words in their name actually mean"; and my second thought is, "I must not be in the demographic they're trying to appeal to."

Answer (score 0):

As I read it, your basic question is "are the two definitions contradictory?" As "smug" is commonly used today, it has a negative connotation. In general, one would not be pleased to be described as "smug," to this extent smugness is similar to hubris, "overbearing pride or presumption." On the face of it,  the second (which doesn't seem negative) and third (which does seem negative) definitions are contradictory. But then you have the phrase "giving the impression," which to me means the person described is actively projecting his correctness and respectability, which is boasting and definitely has a negative connotation. So, if the definition were simply "correctness and respectability," the contradiction would be undeniable, but "impressing" one's C&R on the world brings it so close to definition three, that the contradiction fades.