# About an adjective "lurid"

Tags: word-usage

A textbook gives me a word, "lurid". Merriam defines as following.

[image]

In today's English society, which definition is commonly used?
(I am asking since the definition of 3 seems subtly different.)

Comment: I'm not sure how this could be easily answered objectively. For me, **3b** is the usual interpretation of the word.

Comment: Thank you. That's enough. Since the dictionaries, the first and important souse for English Language Learners, ( though here is not ELL, kindly let me participate. ) has many definitions and I am not sure **which is really alive** today. Like I have a question before link[https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/454182/about-a-word-smug]

Comment: Okay, I'll keep it in my mind.

Comment: @Mari-Lou is that true of M-W, that it orders by date? OED does that but M-W doesn't give real life citations so it is unclear.

Comment: @Mari-Lou My question was about the order of entries in M-W. Is it by date of use or by popularity or some other? You say date but I am skeptical. Can you confirm that M-W ordered by date?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I had assumed that the most common definitions were at the top, so was slightly surprised to see the one that seemed most obvious to me at the bottom! But checking the online version, it is the other way round: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lurid

Comment: Actually, the reason why I upload the pic is because if the first definition is the one, then I less ask anywhere. So please understand I just uploaded the pic as a whole just in order to show every definitions rather than a sentence by sentence.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - It's a toss-up between listing the most common definition first, or the one that is the basis of the others.  In this case this dictionary appears to emphasize origin vs frequency.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I checked [M-W orders senses historically](https://www.merriam-webster.com/help/explanatory-notes/dict-definitions): "The order of senses within an entry is historical: the sense known to have been first used in English is entered first." So you are right. (but only for M-W and OED - not every dictionary will do it this way so I wasn't sure).

Comment: @KentaroTomono Whatever your primary motivation, you should edit you question and cut and paste the entry rather than screen shot.

Comment: I think this type of question cannot be answered.  What do you mean by "today's English society"? That is an odd formulation. English is a very rich language semantically, and talking about English society is rather odd. Societies don't use vocabulary. Individuals use vocabulary and only by reading in context or hearing a word in context can a reader or listener know how a word is being used. If, that is, they know its multiple meanings....

Comment: Should I have used "most commonly used definition in today's English world"? As I said earlier, I asked this question like such a thing like below before happened.link[english.stackexchange.com/questions/454182/about-a-word-smug]

Comment: @KentaroTomono - don’t worry too much about comments. Just keep in mind to show your reasearch whenever you have a question, you are welcome!

Comment: @Mari-LouA [This thread just having re-surfaced], it's clear that _Webster’s New World College Dictionary, 4th Edn. – 2010_ with << **lurid** [American English] adjective: 
(1)  [Rare] deathly pale; wan // (2)  glowing through a haze, as flames enveloped by smoke // (3) (a)  vivid in a harsh or shocking way; startling; sensational / (b)  characterized by violent passion or crime _a lurid tale_ >> can't follow the 'the most common definitions are always listed at the top' protocol. OED is a historic dictionary and orders senses chronologically, but do you know what Websters claims to do here?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No, I don't. I made an erroneous assumption based on what I thought I knew. Comments now deleted.

Comment: You don't know where to access this stuff, do you, @Mari-Lou? It used to be easy ... page iv, say. I've come across other examples where I consider some orderings very suspect (some are obviously just down to differences in samples). You're quite right to recommend comparing dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may find the following [extract from a 2015 article from K Publishing](https://www.wineverygame.com/words/lurid.html) helpful. As you can see lurid has different meanings and can be used in different contexts, some of which are less common than they used to be.

> - Lurid, though a short word, holds a few different meanings and uses. ***The most common use of lurid is to describe the color of objects with a bright or unnatural glow.*** This can illustrate things like chemically enhanced colors on foods, displeasing fluorescent signs, or the reddish hue of a fire behind smoke. This description tends to hold a negative connotation, as the aesthetic of the object being described is unattractive and not well perceived by observers.
> - ***In journalism specifically, lurid relates to the writing technique of using a piece's shock value to gain popularity. This happens when journalists attempt to grab the readers' attention with graphic and explicit details or images, especially when writing of crimes, violence, or sexual matters***. In this sense, lurid qualities are usually viewed negatively, as they can appear unexpectedly, offend readers, and even prove distractive from real issues.
> - The original definition of lurid described a wan appearance of a gray or yellow tone; however, the word's popularity has been in decline since the 1700s. ***Lurid was most commonly used to describe the rotting skin or teeth of sick people, or even the dead. It could also describe things that caused people's skin to pale, such as poisonous herbs, horrific sights, or death.***
> - ***Another less common usage of lurid characterizes behavior as being savage and outrageous in nature***. This usage describes a behavior as being violent or gruesome, similar to the journalistic definition of the word. Lurid behavior is understood to affront people or causes dissenting repercussions.

Usage examples:

> *The lurid shade of the snack made the parents wary of giving it to their children.The crime show gave such lurid details that she couldn't watch it anymore.Example: After several weeks in the hospital, his skin became lurid from lack of sunlight.Example: Her lurid actions in the past prevented her from having hope for a positive future.*

(wineverygame.com)

[Etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/word/lurid):

> - ***1650s, "pale, wan," from Latin luridus "pale yellow, ghastly, the color of bruises," a word of uncertain origin and etymology***, perhaps cognate with Greek khloros "pale green, greenish-yellow" (see Chloe), or connected to Latin lividus (see livid).
> - ***It has more to do with the interplay of light and darkness than it does with color. It suggests a combination of light and gloom***; "Said, e.g. of the sickly pallor of the skin in disease, or of the aspect of things when the sky is overcast" [OED]; "having the character of a light which does not show the colors of objects" [Century Dictionary]. Meaning "glowing in the darkness" is from 1727 ("of the color or appearance of dull smoky flames" - Century Dictionary]. In scientific use (1767) "of a dingy brown or yellowish-brown color" [OED]. ***The figurative sense of "sensational" is first attested 1850, via the notion of "ominous" (if from the flames sense) or "ghastly" (if from the older sense)***.

Comment: Thanks! As you say, from the perspective of the color such as the definition 1 **wan and ghastly pale in appearance** connotes somewhat "unhealthy"? sense of color, which -- could -- leads to the meaning of 3.